# How to use go-bindata with Gin?

Tags: go

I am going to package the static file into an Golang executable file. How to use go-bindata (or go-bindata-assetfs) in Gin? There are missing examples on the Internet.

Comment: Have you tried using [go-assets](https://github.com/jessevdk/go-assets)? They have [an example](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin#build-a-single-binary-with-templates) for it in gin repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you would need to roll your own static file handler using `go-bindata`...

```
func bindataStaticHandler(c *gin.Context) {
   path := c.Param("filepath")
   data, err := Asset("pub/style/foo.css")
   if err != nil {
    // Asset was not found.
   }
   // Write asset
   c.Writer.Write(data)
   // Handle errors here too and cache headers
}
```

And you declare the route (after creating a gin engine)

```
router.GET("/static/*filepath", bindataStaticHandler)
```

This is something very rudimentary but just to show you how you would do it